# how to create multiple csv files using one csv master file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, file

I have 1 CSV file named `master.csv` with two columns named `name` and `product`.

I want to create multiple CSV files using `master.csv`.

The new files contain 100 pieces of data from `master.csv` with the headers `name` and `product`.

I want to copy data from `master.csv` and paste it into another file.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the `chunksize` parameter when you read in the master csv file. This will break the input csv into chunks of size `chunksize`, then you can write each of the chunks to a separate csv file.

```
import pandas as pd

for chunk_index, chunk in enumerate(pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer="master.csv", chunksize=100)):
    chunk.to_csv(path_or_buf=f"chunk_{chunk_index}.csv", header=True, index=False)
```

Specifying `header=True` will keep the `name` and `product` labels at the top of your csv files. Specifying `index=False` will tell pandas *not* to add a third column with the original row numbers of your data. Wrapping the `read_csv` call in `enumerate` will allow you to use the `chunk_index` to give each chunk file a unique name.

For some more information on the `chunksize` parameter, see the pandas docs on `read_csv`: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas-read-csv